# Angular2 npm-install error (node-gyp rebuild)

Tags: node.js, npm, angular, npm-install

I've recently started following a new Angular2 tutorial. I was provided an angular2-seed folder as part of the project files, but when trying to install dependencies in the project folder, I get these errors:

```
D:\Angular.JS\angular2-seed>npm install

> bufferutil@1.2.1 install D:\Angular.JS\angular2-seed\node_modules\bufferutil
> node-gyp rebuild


D:\Angular.JS\angular2-seed\node_modules\bufferutil>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" re
build )  else (node "" rebuild )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\gyp_main.py", line 13, in <module>
    import gyp
  File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    import gyp.input
  File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\input.py", line 15, in <module>
    import multiprocessing
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\__init__.py", line 84, in <module>
    import _multiprocessing
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 n’est pas une application Win32 valide.
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:305:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\Angular.JS\angular2-seed\node_modules\bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v5.7.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.2.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN install:bufferutil@1.2.1 bufferutil@1.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN install:bufferutil@1.2.1 Exit status 1

> utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install D:\Angular.JS\angular2-seed\node_modules\utf-8-validate
> node-gyp rebuild


D:\Angular.JS\angular2-seed\node_modules\utf-8-validate>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js
" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\gyp_main.py", line 13, in <module>
    import gyp
  File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    import gyp.input
  File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\input.py", line 15, in <module>
    import multiprocessing
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\__init__.py", line 84, in <module>
    import _multiprocessing
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 n’est pas une application Win32 valide.
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:305:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\Angular.JS\angular2-seed\node_modules\utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v5.7.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.2.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN install:utf-8-validate@1.2.1 utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN install:utf-8-validate@1.2.1 Exit status 1

> angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 postinstall D:\Angular.JS\angular2-seed
> typings install

'typings' n’est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.

npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.8
npm WARN angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v5.7.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.6.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 postinstall: `typings install`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 postinstall script 'typings install'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular2-quickstart package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     typings install
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular2-quickstart
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular2-quickstart
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\Angular.JS\angular2-seed\npm-debug.log

D:\Angular.JS\angular2-seed>
```

I'll be looking forward to your answers.

Comment: try updating `node-gyp` to the latest version

Comment: Tried that with   npm install -g node-gyp@latest, but to no avail.